# How to reference environmental variables in WORKSPACE?

Tags: bazel

If a project has an external dependency to software that's installed locally and can't be managed with `new_http_archive` or `new_git_repository` because licensing or size issues prevent it from being downloaded, is there a way to have the path specified with `new_local_repository` use an environmental variable?

Looking at the [comments](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/746#issuecomment-169085318) on [Issue #746](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/746), it looks like this was solved in some way. But I can't find any documentation on how to do it.

Comment: [bazel issue 746](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/746) seems to be specifically about the android SDK.

Comment: That might be the focus, but it also references a more general [solution](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/746#issuecomment-261351265).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Looking at the comments on Issue #746, it looks like this was solved in some way. But I can't find any documentation on how to do it.

Thanks for checking for existing bugs! That bug is almost 2 years old though. Bazel has changed a ton since then.

For this problem, I think you should write your own repository rule in a `.bzl` file.

Repository rules are allowed to perform non-hermetic operations, read the environment, look at the whole filesystem, etc. Normal build rules are not, nor do they have access to the environment or the full filesystem.

Your repository rule should check the envvar's value and write a `BUILD` file that Bazel will use in the external repository that your rule created.

Look at my answer here for an example: [Call llvm-config --prefix and use it in a BUILD rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928653/call-llvm-config-prefix-and-use-it-in-a-build-rule/43936381)

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way in bazel is to place the tools in the source code repository too, because that's the only way to have reproducible builds.

However, I think [you can use environment variables as part of an action](https://bazel.build/designs/2016/06/21/environment.html) and [you can reference environment variables in rules](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/configuration.html#default_shell_env).

I haven't tested, but I think the rule will look like this `proprietary_tool.bzl`:

```
def _proprietary_tool_impl(ctx):
    env = ctx.configuration.default_shell_env
    ctx.actions.run(
      inputs=ctx.attr.srcs,
      outputs=ctx.attr.out,
      executable=env['PROPRIETARY_TOOL_PATH'] + "/bin/tool",
    )

proprietary_tool = rule(
    implementation=_proprietary_tool_impl,
    attrs={}, # Add attributes needed by the proprietary tool
)
```

Comment: Including the tools in the source repository is definitely not a viable solution for open-source projects that want to optionally integrate with proprietary, licensed, 3rd party software.

I was able to get this to work with [repository_rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/globals.html#repository_rule). I think that might be the better approach since it has an `environ` argument that can be used to express a dependency on the environmental variable.