# please tell me a better way to have a multiplatform WORKSPACE in Bazel

Tags: c++, bazel

This is an example in my actual WORKSPACE to enable TUT (Template Unit Test) to be seen by my projects, whether I am testing them on Windows or Linux.

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "win32_tut",
    path = "/d/diego/progs/c++/lib/tut/",
    build_file_content = """
cc_library(
    name = "tut",
    srcs = glob([
        "tut/*.hpp",
    ]),
    hdrs = glob([
        "*.h",
    ]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
""",
)

new_local_repository(
    name = "linux_tut",
    path = "/usr/include/",
    build_file_content = """
cc_library(
    name = "tut",
    srcs = glob([
        "tut/*.hpp",
    ]),
    hdrs = glob([
        "tut.h",
    ]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
""",
)

new_local_repository(
    name = "tut",
    path = ".",
    build_file_content = """
cc_library(
    name = "tut",
    deps = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:windows": ["@win32_tut//:tut"],
        "//conditions:default": ["@linux_tut//:tut"],
    }),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
""",
)
```

All my cc_test rules are successfully depending on `"@tut//:tut"`.
That is working for me, but it looks like I am abusing the WORKSPACE file. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks good to me.

> it looks like I am abusing the WORKSPACE file

Alternatively, create a custom repository rule that [detects the OS](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_os.html#name) [1], [creates a symlink](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#symlink) to the `d:/diego/progs/c++/lib/tut` or `/usr/include` directory, and [creates a BUILD file](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#file) with just one cc_library, globbing all files under the symlink.

See an [example for a custom repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43936381).

---

[1] e.g. `repository_ctx.os.name.lower().startswith("windows")`

Comment: I am creating a new local repo with a meaningless path only to merge the two platform specific repos. That looks like exploiting to me.

Comment: your updated answer seems to be the right thing to do here, but I have no experience with skylark at all. where can I find examples of custom repository rules?
thanks :)